# Supabase functions in same network as database to reduce latency

Tags: postgresql, architecture, latency, supabase

I'm playing around with Supabase and pretty early on I'm getting stuck with the following issue: it doesn't seem to be a way to store my application on the same network as my supabase database?

This means my middle layer API endpoints will waste 300ms every time they want to fetch data from PostgreSQL. Some endpoints can communicate with PostgreSQL a few times, quickly adding up to >1 second response time.

The typical architecture that I've been using for years is to have the database and the application servers in the same virtual private network so that they can communicate with a ~2ms latency instead of 300ms, is there a similar approach that's doable with supabase?

Comment: Supabase creates APIs automatically for you from your database schema, but have you used them? You can directly call them from your client-side code using any of Supabase's client libraries. Since the auto-generated APIs are in the same network as the database, the response is efficient and quick.

Comment: Correct but I’m looking to serve an API endpoint to my customers who want to integrate my service and some features of this API requires many subsequent DB queries

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options:

1. **Have your application run on AWS with region close to your Supabase instance** - Every Supabase instance is just a EC2 instance on AWS, and you should be able to choose which region you want to host your database when you first create your project. Having your application on AWS in the same region should bring down the latency significantly.
2. **Self host Supabase** - You can always self host Supabase, which would give you the freedom to put your application in the same network. You can follow the Supabase self hosting guide [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/self-hostin).

Comment: 1. Running an AWS in the same region will be nowhere near the expected latency of being in the same network - as soon as it's routed outside of the datacenter you're losing too much time.

2. The hassle of self hosting supabase seems greater than the benefit of not having to run a middle layer between the front end and the database.

It seems that this is the main limitation to supabase - as soon as you want to serve an API to customers you're blocked.